# Numerical Data - High Volume + High Velocity + Fast Retrieval

Tags: hadoop, cassandra, bigdata, analytics, apache-storm

My data looks something like 10 Million numerical values (real + binary) per frame (think array i.e. 10 Million elements in an row of an array) and there are around 100 frames/second. Kind of Time-Series.

The challenge for me is:

(1) Storage - Amount of Data

(2) Handling Velocity of Data

(3) Real Time Analytics

Is Cassandra suitable for this? Can anybody guide me a bit on the application architecture (Think hadoop, cassandra, kafka, storm etc.) which will work out in above scenario (from a very high level point of view).

I know I have asked something big. I need a direction to go before experimenting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As storage engine or Handling velocity of data, Cassandra and Hadoop will pass with flying colors.

Now coming into real time part, Cassandra can provide you a near real time solution, where as Hadoop alone is not enough (batch nature, map-reduce jobs). You can try with Hadoop with Storm, that will give you near real time capability, but it will increase the complexity of the solution (using spouts and bolts). Also 
you can try some rule engine, which will provide you an added advantage towards real time solution.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. Can you clarify a bit more about how you would integrate Hadoop+Storm for real-time? Are you suggesting to have two independent pieces - Storm for real-time and Hadoop for batching?